# Need help understanding the observer pattern with PHP

Tags: php, design-patterns, web

I need help understanding the observer pattern with PHP.

A web browser typically displays one page at a time. Would it not make sense to conclude that a design pattern can only update one page at a time, whereas the subject is designed to update multiple observables at once? I was considering having the observers call a subject's method to retrieve a static variable as an update option.

I have taken this route to have a learning experience with the observer pattern and to possibly create an alternative to sessions for communicating from page to page. In my web application I trying to find a solution for refreshing my web pages when a user has logged in or out without using sessions.

I appreciate your input. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A web application communicates to server over http protocol, which is stateless. So you have to poll the server with requests to catch up with events occurring. Work around for this is sessions, which you don't want to use.

But using [WebRTC](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/) and creating a server [using sockets in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php) you can achieve observer pattern with php as you expect.

Only latest Chrome and Firefox supports WebRTC.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I never heard of WebRTC until now. I'll do some research on it. I have an ebook on using sockets. I'll take a some time for that too. Again thank you for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: I'm appreciative of Saravana Kumar's answer, however I'm researching the possibilities of using callbacks to accomplish communication between my web pages without JavaScript, sessions or sockets. PHP code is handled on the server so I can't see why this would not be possible. I'm still opened to other's comments and answers.